# Implementing a file-like object that writes to a queue

Tags: python, multithreading, io, python-multithreading

I want to parallelize this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import requests

# the 'in memory file' I use at the moment
bytesIO = io.BytesIO()

data = np.random.randint(0, 256, (30, 30))
np.savez(bytesIO, data=data)

# go to the beginning of the buffer again
bytesIO.seek(0)
# upload the file to a different server
requests.post("http://example.org/, files={'file': bytesIO},
              data={'filename': 'My_File'})
```

In here

1. the data is generated,
2. he data is sent in the request.

I want the data to be transmitted as it is being serialized to the buffer.  Probably using 2 threads, connected by a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

For the transmission, requests supports [streaming uploads](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads).

But `np.savez` and also `requests` both expect a file-like object to read/write from/to.  The queue is not file-like, and the `BytesIO` is not thread-safe.

What's the best way to solve this?